# Flot Charts: How to set time period from comboBox to display on x-axis?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flot

I have a Flot chart, that displays amount on y-axis and time on x-axis. I want the user to select the period of time that is shown on x-axis from a comboBox. For Example comboBox1 = fromDate; comboBox2 = toDate; and this Period shown on the x-axis of the chart.

So here is my code. Until now, I get values from all the time. So how to set it up to use a period by using the fromDate and toDate variables?

Hope someone can help me.

```
   <script>
   var chartDataArray = [<?php echo $dataString ?>];
  </script>
            <script>
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ chartDataArray ], { xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%d/%m/%y"} });
                });



            </script>
```

Comment: I think I am searching something like:
`xaxis: {
        min: (new Date(2013, 0, 13)).getTime(),
        max: (new Date(2013, 1, 13)).getTime(),
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",
        minTickSize: [1, "day"]
    },`